# Ember classNameBindings not being called for the sample program

Tags: ember.js

I am facing issue with class name bindings. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amareswar/nDMAC/8/) code for the same. Logging the number of times binding is called. It is never called when the property is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have a couple of issues here.  Primarily, if you want properties to be recalculated when the contents of an array change, you cannot just depend on the array property itself - it will only fire a change when it is set to a different array.  If you depend on `myArray.@each` instead, your property will be recalculated when the contents change as well.

Next, your template containing the span isn't rendering because you're providing an empty view template in your handlebars view declaration.  Change your "HTML" to:

```
{{view App.contact}}
```

and your span will appear.

Finally, running `Ember.run.sync()` does not appear to be enough here.  I am not as clear on the reason behind this but...computed properties only update when read (versus observers that update immediately).  I would hypothesize that since your computed property is only used by the view and the view may only update on a subsequent run through the JS event loop, your computed property is recalculated only once for all your changes to "subordinates".  Change your code to use timeouts and it'll work fine.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDMAC/10/) with all of my proposed changes.